# Time difference between 2 consecutive lines

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server v18.0

I have the folowing table:

[image: TestEquipmentStatistics]
The table represents the time use for the test equipment.

The character `C_` represents connect operation and the `D_` represents disconnect operation

How can I create query that return the time use for range of dates of specific device name?

Comment: Can you provide the table structure DDL and a sample set of output data please?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table tbl (DeviceName varchar(10), Connect_Statistics varchar(30));

insert into tbl values
('reg', 'C_09-12-2018 11:36:40'),
('reg', 'D_09-12-2018 11:38:52'),
('reg', 'C_09-12-2018 14:46:09'),
('reg', 'D_09-12-2018 14:46:18'),
('reg', 'C_09-12-2018 12:03:18'),
('reg', 'D_09-12-2018 12:03:25');
GO
```

Assuming than for each `C_` type there is a corresponding `D_`, and that there are no intersection between dates of different records, you can use next solution:

> ```
> with ct as
> (
>   select 
>       DeviceName, 
>       substring(Connect_Statistics, 1, 1) as [Type],
>       cast(substring(Connect_Statistics, 3, 19) as datetime) as [Date]
>   from   
>       tbl
> )
> select
>     t1.DeviceName,
>     t1.[Date] as StartDate,
>     t3.EndDate,
>     DATEDIFF(second, t1.[Date], t3.EndDate) DiffSeconds
> from
>     ct t1
> cross apply (select top 1
>                [Date] as EndDate
>              from
>                ct t2
>              where 
>                t2.DeviceName = t1.DeviceName
>                and t2.[Type] = 'D'
>                and t2.[Date] > t1.[Date]
>              order by
>                t2.DeviceName,
>                t2.[Date] asc) t3
> where
>     t1.[Type] = 'C'
> order by
>     t1.DeviceName,
>     t1.[Date];
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> DeviceName | StartDate           | EndDate             | DiffSeconds
> :--------- | :------------------ | :------------------ | ----------:
> reg        | 12/09/2018 11:36:40 | 12/09/2018 11:38:52 |         132
> reg        | 12/09/2018 12:03:18 | 12/09/2018 12:03:25 |           7
> reg        | 12/09/2018 14:46:09 | 12/09/2018 14:46:18 |           9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=82bc8e5dda9371df2633346b21bdae65)*